# Graph Tour with Uniform Cost Search in Java

Tags: java, search, graph, artificial-intelligence

I'm new to this site, so hopefully you guys don't mind helping a nub.

Anyway, I've been asked to write code to find the shortest cost of a graph tour on a particular graph, whose details are read in from file. The graph is shown below:

http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/8907/graphr.jpg

This is for an Artificial Intelligence class, so I'm expected to use a decent enough search method (brute force has been allowed, but not for full marks).

I've been reading, and I think that what I'm looking for is an A* search with constant heuristic value, which I believe is a uniform cost search. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to apply this in Java.

Basically, here's what I have:

Vertex class -

```
ArrayList<Edge> adjacencies;
String name;
int costToThis;
```

Edge class -

```
final Vertex target;
public final int weight;
```

Now at the moment, I'm struggling to work out how to apply the uniform cost notion to my desired goal path. Basically I have to start on a particular node, visit all other nodes, and end on that same node, with the lowest cost.

As I understand it, I could use a PriorityQueue to store all of my travelled paths, but I can't wrap my head around how I show the goal state as the starting node with all other nodes visited.

Here's what I have so far, which is pretty far off the mark:

```
public static void visitNode(Vertex vertex) {
      ArrayList<Edge> firstEdges = vertex.getAdjacencies();
      for(Edge e : firstEdges) {
         e.target.costToThis = e.weight + vertex.costToThis;
         queue.add(e.target);
      }
      Vertex next = queue.remove();
      visitNode(next);
   }
```

Initially this takes the starting node, then recursively visits the first node in the PriorityQueue (the path with the next lowest cost).

My problem is basically, how do I stop my program from following a path specified in the queue if that path is at the goal state? The queue currently stores Vertex objects, but in my mind this isn't going to work as I can't store whether other vertices have been visited inside a Vertex object.

Help is much appreciated!
Josh

**EDIT: I should mention that paths previously visited may be visited again. In the case I provided this isn't beneficial, but there may be a case where visiting a node previously visited to get to another node would lead to a shorter path (I think). So I can't just do it based on nodes already visited (this was my first thought too)**

Comment: "... I've been asked to write code ..." - by whom? A teacher maybe? If so, please label your question 'homework' ...

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, it is homework. My bad. I hope this is within the rules. I should be clear, I'm not asking for fully written code (I don't want to cheat myself out of an education!), just an explanation (preferably using standard libraries) of how I could perform a search the right way.

Comment: EDIT: I should mention that paths previously visited may be visited again. In the case I provided this isn't beneficial, but there may be a case where visiting a node previously visited to get to another node would lead to a shorter path (I think). So I can't just do it based on nodes already visited (this was my first thought too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments:

1) When you set costToThis of a vertex, you override the existing value, and this affects all paths in the queue, since the vertex is shared by many paths. I would not store the costToThis as a part of Vertex. Instead, I would have defined a Path class that contains the total cost of the path plus a list of nodes composing it.

2) I am not sure if I understood correctly your problem with the goal state. However, the way I would add partial paths to the queue is as follows: if the path has a length<N-1, a return to any visited node is illegal. When length=N-1, the only option is returning to the starting node. You can add visitedSet to your Path class (as a HashSet), so that you can check efficiently whether a given node has been visited or not.

I hope this helps...

Comment: 1) Yeah, I found this bug out the hard way, when my ordered lists were correct, but the costToThis values were obviously wrong as they were being overwritten. The Path class idea was one I had, but hadn't yet implemented, though it obviously makes a lot of sense, so thanks.

2) I forgot to mention that any path previously travelled can be travelled again. In the case I provided this isn't beneficial for any path, but that is using example data, and may not always be true. My search needs to travel all nodes at least once and then end up back on the starting node.

Comment: I solved this problem. Implemented a Path class, and used my priority queue to sort the Paths, whilst adding each new Vertex and associate edge cost to it. Following a uniform cost search using the queue, and then returning with the goal once all nodes had been visited >= 1, and current node == starting node. Thanks again for your help!